# Allow a supervisor child take advantage of restarts, but not kill the supervisor once it passes max restarts?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor that manages a fairly volatile set of children -- they often die due to external causes, e.g. their network conn being terminated. Erlang's supervision system is brilliant for this -- it just restarts them back up and everything rolls on.

The problem occurs when one of the children has a serious problem with the connection and hits the supervisor's max restart limit, at which point the supervisor kills all children, and then kills itself. Awesome, this is specified in the documentation. However, my ideal behavior would be for the supervisor to give up restarting that particular child, and continue.

I know I can implement this using separate processes which monitors the supervisor, but this seems like overkill.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: my understanding is that children of a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor all have the same specification. then I do not understand how "that particular" child that just died is different from the rest? How would your supervisor know that it needs not restart a child when it dies?

Comment: Hey @akonsu thanks the comment, but as I just mentioned in the other thread, I'm concerned not with the child dying once, but enough times to hit the max restart frequency.

Comment: I do not understand what you want the supervisor to do exactly when the supervisor reaches the restart limit. Given that, as far as I understand, it does not count restarts for specific children, but total restarts.

Comment: Ah! I'd always thought that the frequency was per-child, but it looks like you're right. Well, that changes the whole ball game. Thank you! And, in that case, the sol'n given by @Pascal makes even more sense.

Comment: I have add to my answer a small example of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try it but I suggest that the supervisor launches another supervisor (one per process) with the restart strategy `simple_one_for_one`, and the restart child spec `transient`.

Then this supervisor launch the process itself with the restart strategy `one_for_one` and the restart child spec `permanent`, and the maxrestarts and the maxtime fitting your need.

There is something strange in your question, you say that the supervisor kills all the children that were started when it reach the maxrestart for one faulty child, I thought that the simple_one_for_one strategy left the workers die by themselves.

**[edit]**
As I was curious to test this idea, I wrote a small set of module to test it.

her is the code of the top supervisor:

```
-module (factory).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, start_process/1]).


-define(CHILD(I, Arglist), {I, {I, start_link, [Arglist]}, temporary, 5000, supervisor, [I]}).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, { {simple_one_for_one, 0, 10}, [?CHILD(proc_sup, [])]} }.

start_process(Arglist)->
    supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [Arglist]).
```

Then the code of the intermediate one, in charge to restart a few time a process in case of problem:

```
-module (proc_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/2]).
-export([init/1]).

-define(CHILD(Mod, Start, Arglist), {Mod, {Mod, Start, Arglist}, permanent, 5000, worker, [Mod]}).

start_link(_,Arglist) ->
    io:format("proc_sup arg = ~p~n",[Arglist]),
    supervisor:start_link(?MODULE, [Arglist]).

init([[Mod,Start|[Arglist]]]) ->
    {ok, { {one_for_one, 5, 10}, [?CHILD(Mod,Start,Arglist)]} }.
```

And then the code of a small modules that can be stopped, receive a message, be programmed to die after a certain time, in order to test the mechanism.

```
-module(dumb).
-export([start_link/1,loop/2]).

start_link(Arg) ->
    io:format("dumb start param = ~p~n",[Arg]),
    {ok,spawn_link(?MODULE,loop,[Arg,init])}.


loop({die,T},_) ->
    receive
    after T -> ok
    end;
loop(Arg,init) ->
    io:format("loop pid ~p with arg ~p~n",[self(),Arg]),
    loop(Arg,0);
loop(Arg,N) ->
    io:format("loop ~p (~p) cycle ~p~n",[Arg,self(),N]),
    receive
        stop -> 'restart_:o)';
        _ -> loop(Arg,N+1)
    end.
```

Finally a copy of the shell execution:

```
1> factory:start_link().
{ok,<0.37.0>}
2> 
2> factory:start_process([dumb,start_link,[loop_1]]).
proc_sup arg = [dumb,start_link,[loop_1]]
dumb start param = loop_1
loop pid <0.40.0> with arg loop_1
loop loop_1 (<0.40.0>) cycle 0
{ok,<0.39.0>}
3> 
3> factory:start_process([dumb,start_link,[loop_1]]).
proc_sup arg = [dumb,start_link,[loop_1]]
dumb start param = loop_1
loop pid <0.43.0> with arg loop_1
loop loop_1 (<0.43.0>) cycle 0
{ok,<0.42.0>}
4> 
4> factory:start_process([dumb,start_link,[loop_2]]).
proc_sup arg = [dumb,start_link,[loop_2]]
dumb start param = loop_2
loop pid <0.46.0> with arg loop_2
loop loop_2 (<0.46.0>) cycle 0
{ok,<0.45.0>}
5> 
5> pid(0, 2310, 0) ! hello.                          
hello
6> 
6> pid(0, 40, 0) ! hello.  
loop loop_1 (<0.40.0>) cycle 1
hello
7> pid(0, 40, 0) ! hello.
loop loop_1 (<0.40.0>) cycle 2
hello
8> pid(0, 40, 0) ! hello.
loop loop_1 (<0.40.0>) cycle 3
hello
9> pid(0, 43, 0) ! hello.
loop loop_1 (<0.43.0>) cycle 1
hello
10> pid(0, 43, 0) ! hello.
loop loop_1 (<0.43.0>) cycle 2
hello
11> pid(0, 40, 0) ! stop. 
dumb start param = loop_1
stop
loop pid <0.54.0> with arg loop_1
loop loop_1 (<0.54.0>) cycle 0
12> pid(0, 40, 0) ! stop.
stop
13> pid(0, 54, 0) ! stop.
dumb start param = loop_1
stop
loop pid <0.57.0> with arg loop_1
loop loop_1 (<0.57.0>) cycle 0
14> pid(0, 57, 0) ! hello.
loop loop_1 (<0.57.0>) cycle 1
hello
15> factory:start_process([dumb,start_link,[{die,5}]]).
proc_sup arg = [dumb,start_link,[{die,5}]]
dumb start param = {die,5}
{ok,<0.60.0>}
16> 
dumb start param = {die,5}
dumb start param = {die,5}
dumb start param = {die,5}
dumb start param = {die,5}
dumb start param = {die,5}
16> factory:start_process([dumb,start_link,[{die,50000}]]).
proc_sup arg = [dumb,start_link,[{die,50000}]]
dumb start param = {die,50000}
{ok,<0.68.0>}
17> 
dumb start param = {die,50000}
17>
```

Comment: Hmm regarding your last point, it could be that the children are just dying, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm observing, and the documentation states that "Because a simple_one_for_one supervisor could have many children, it shuts them all down at same time. So, order in which they are stopped is not defined. For the same reason, it could have an overhead with regards to the Shutdown strategy." But! thank you for the suggestion -- I'll give it a go!

Comment: this quote from the documentation does not imply that this shutdown happens when a child crashes. in addition, the documentation clearly says that `simple_one_for_one` supervisor, is a simplified version of `one_for_one`, which in turn, just restarts the failed child, and does not kill all of them.

Comment: @akonsu Yes, a `one_for_one` or `simple_one_for_one` supervisor restarts the failed child when it dies, but if that child continues to die such that it achieves the maximum restart frequency "the supervisor terminates all child processes and then itself". This is the behavior I'm trying to work around. Sorry -- is my understanding wrong?

Comment: in first edit I forgot to come back to `temporary` in the restart strategy of the factory supervisor; now it is correct.

Comment: I made the test to better understand the behavior of the `simple_one_for_one`, when I kill the factory supervisor, all children die. So I was wrong. It seems that the difference with other strategy. is that the order of children termination is not guaranteed